# How to generate jar file from spring boot application using gradle?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

> I am creating a spring boot application using gradle. I need to create
> a jar which include all needed libraries for deploying on (aws) ec2
> instance.

---

I am trying to create a jar by...

1)click on project structure

2)then click on Artifact

3)click on + **->** jar **->** from modules with dependencies **->** select project **->** select main class

4)click on ok with default settings

5)click on build tab

6)I got a jar file but it doesn't contain classes.

Comment: as explained in the Spring Boot reference guide `./gradlew build` nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Terminal/Command Prompt` to generate `jar` using `Gradle`

To generate jar without running test cases

```
./gradlew build -x test
```

If you want to run the test cases before creating jar, then

```
./gradlew build
```

Answer (score -1):

First make sure you have downloaded gradle and set up in your system variable.
to check this simply run gradle -v in your cmd.

> **Under System Variables select Path, then click Edit. Add an entry for
> C:\Gradle\gradle-6.5.1\bin. Click OK to save.**

Now you simply goes to project directory and run

> **./gradlew build -x test**

Now you get your executable jar file